Deploying and Routing Dash Applications on Railway with Nginx as reverse Proxy
I've developed a web application based on Plotly's Dash in Python.
App1: auth, handles user authentication and registration.
App2: quickbio, is an application for processing biological data.
Each app is a standalone Dash application, meaning it has its own configuration:
app = dash.Dash(...)

I've been able to communicate between both applications using Nginx as follows:
I deploy app1.
I deploy app2.
I route them using a reverse proxy with Nginx under the same domain, communicating both independent applications.
What I'd like to know is the following: Is it possible to do this natively on Railway?
I've seen that you can deploy independent applications from GitHub. By going to "New Project" and adding each repository there, So, from there, I would have to create a third "repository/script" that is responsible for joining the applications in a similar way to the Nginx script I have, or can this be done natively with Railway?
Regarding costs, how different would it be compared to me creating a Docker container that runs everything as a monolith with the routing I already have?
I'm interested in keeping everything separate (as microservices) because if I need to add new features, I would only have to update my GitHub code and Railway would take care of the rest, and I would have a more real separation than having all the code in a single Docker container.
I would like to know if there are other options that you know of, thank you for your help!
There is a code snippet of how i handle the reverse proxy with nginx
def generate_nginx_config(modules: List[ModuleType]) -> str:
    config = """
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    """

    for module in modules:
        module_name = get_module_name(module)
        port = get_app_port(module)
        prefix = get_app_prefix(module)
        if port is None or prefix is None:
            print(f"Error: No se pudo obtener el puerto o prefijo para {module_name}")
            continue

        config += f"""
    location {prefix} {{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:{port};
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }}
    """

        print(f"Ruta de Nginx para {module_name}: http://localhost{prefix}")

    config += "}\n"

    config_path = os.path.expanduser("~/dash_apps_nginx.conf")
    with open(config_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(config)

    print(f"Configuración de Nginx generada en {config_path}")
    return config_path

